# How to read contents of files with Angular 5?

Tags: angular

i want  to read the contents of different files which is taken from input type file

This is my html code:

```
<input id="input-file" type="file" name="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" accept="application/pdf;image/jpeg;image/gif;image/tif;image/tiff;image/jpg;image/png;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"/>
```

This is type script code :

```js
onFileSelected(event) {
  if(event.target.files.length > 0) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      console.log(reader.result);
    };           
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must read the file (i.e by calling `readAsText` for a text file) before logging the result.

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
  var text = reader.result;
  console.log(text );
}    
reader.readAsText(file, encoding);
```

By your requirement and the type file, there are a lot of methods available for you

[readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) : for the image i.e

[readAsBinaryString](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString)